# Polaris Office cannot set Date Format to UK

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, polaris-office

how can we change the input & displaying of dates in Polaris Office to UK format?

The devices are set in Settings/System/Date and Time/Select date format to UK style (dd/mm/yyyy).

The default within Polaris seems to be yyyy/mm/dd. [Other android users wrongly think this is UK format](http://www.transformerforums.com/forum/asus-transformer-tf101-general-discussions/10739-polaris-spreadsheet-need-help.html).

You can change the date format of cells to be any of the following:

- yyyy/mm/dd (default)
- mm/dd/yyyy (US format)
- mm/dd
- dd-month-yy
- dd-month
- month-yy
- month-yy
- month dd, yyyy
- dd month yyyy (almost UK format)

Ideally we need the correct UK date format dd/mm/yy or dd/mm/yyyy as this is already in our source files. We cannot change this (only the format of the cells) as users will be working on files generated from MySQL in MS Access and outputted to .xlsx

This seems an oversight on Polaris part, but I don't see much 'chatter' about it around the web, so should we notify Polaris of this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If an app doesn't work the way you want, or you can't work out how to make it do what you want, it's always appropriate to contact the developer.

You can do this via Google Play: every app has to have an email address or phone number for support, which you can find on that app's page. Many apps also have a "support" or "feedback" option inside the app too.

Even if the answer is that there's no way to do this and they don't intend to add it, at least you know that from the horse's mouth, and of course if they get enough requests they may change their mind and add it. And going the other way, even if there was already a really simple way to do it, and they just tell you how to do it, it lets them know that they need to make it easier to find in future.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I've contacted Polaris and will post back here any response I get as an answer.